# Facebook share button only share the_permalink(), without thumbnail, tilte, excerpt, etc

Tags: php, javascript, social-sharing

I'm trying to add socials to my post. I can share the post, but only the post URL. How could I share the post thumbnail, the Title, the excerpt, the author, etc.

This is what i'm trying:

HTML (in single.php):

```
<div class="share-icons-wrapper">  
    <a href="" onClick="facebookSharer()"><i class="fa fa-facebook share-icon"></i></a>
</div>
```

Js

```
jQuery('.share-icons-wrapper a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});

// Facebook

function facebookSharer(){
window.open( 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href), 
    'facebookWindow', 
    'width=650,height=350');
    return false;
}
```

I don't know wath i'm missing.
Thanks.

Comment: The most important thing is the data that FB scrapes -- use the linter to debug your urls : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ It will gather information in your meta tags using Open Graph protocol when possible: http://opengraphprotocol.org

Answer (score -1):

OK this is ok, it works great!!!. **The problem was that i was testing locally.**